# Mysql call does not work, I'm trying to get orders from today

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyone here that can tell me why this call to mysql does not work?

I have tried for infinity. I'm trying to get the orders that have been out for today! from 00.00 until now

```
   $sqltoday = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM wpd2_posts p JOIN              
   wpd2_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_status = 'wc-completed'
   AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total'
   AND pm.meta_value < 250  AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.post_date) <= 0 ";
```

The script runs really well without AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.post_date) <= 0, but i need it.

Comment: What format is `p.post_date`? Is it `DATETIME`? Also, what happens when you run the query? You get a count of 0, or an error?

Comment: @BenM assuming this is a Wordpress database based on the table names & columns, then post_date is always DATETIME.

Comment: Also, the obvious question - are you sure there are posts for today? Everything else looks fine, though you should change the DATEDIFF to *equals* 0 (i.e. `DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.post_date) = 0`) because Wordpress allows you to specify future dates for posts.

Comment: @FluffyKitten WooCommerce does not allow completed orders in the future though ;)

Comment: @BenM I know, but when it comes to WP I *always* err on the side of caution... you don't know what rogue plugins people are using. They're not all developed by competent developers, to put it politely.

Comment: FluffyKitten : what do you mean?

Comment: yes there are post today